# UITableView not showing iPad running iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview, ios5

I am running across a weird problem that came up out of now where. I'm not sure if it is because I have not updated to Xcode 4.2.1 or if it is iOS 5.

I have an iPad application that runs on OS's 4.0 - 5.0.

I have a UITableView that is contained in a view being shown modally as a form sheet.

The table shows up fine running on 4.x but the table disappears when running on 5.0.

I know everyone has heard this a million times but it literarily was working fine yesterday, I didn't change anything, now it doesn't work. I have a working copy from yesterday that is installed on an extra iPad running iOS 5. Today it doesn't want to work.

Here is how I have it setup, maybe you can spot a problem.

1. The UITableView is created in IB. The datasource and delegate ARE set.
2. The view is being called like so:

> ```
> GuidedSearchPriceViewController *guide = [[GuidedSearchPriceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GuidedSearchPriceViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
> UINavigationController *temp = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:guide]; 
> temp.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet; 
> [guide setModalDelegate:self]; 
> [guide setAppDelegate:self.appDelegate]; 
> temp.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; 
> [self presentModalViewController:temp animated:YES];
> ```

In **iOS 4.x** we get this:
[image: iOS 4.x]

But is **iOS 5** we get this:
[image: iOS 5]

The viewDidLoad method of the Price view is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Tried for testing but still does nothing
    self.table.delegate = self;
    self.table.dataSource = self;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Type" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextScreen)];
    addButton.enabled = NO;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(dismiss)];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancel;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], RP_iPad_FormsheetBackground]]];

    } else
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], RP_BackgroundImage]]];

    // Make sure the background of the table is clear. I have also tried taking this out
    // to resolve the disappearing issue but it has no effect. 
    if ([self.table respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundView)]) {
        [self.table setBackgroundView:nil];
        [self.table setBackgroundView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
        [self.table setBackgroundColor:UIColor.clearColor]; 
    }

    priceList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"$750", @"$1000", @"$1250", @"$1500", @"$1750", @"$2000", @"$2000 +", nil];

}
```

Thank you very much for any help, and as always thank you for your time.

---

**ANSWER**

I managed to figure out what the problem was but I am not sure why it is occurring. Maybe someone can shed some light on it.

I had to insert

`[table reloadData];`

at the end of `-(void)viewDidLoad`

I'm not sure why it has to be there in iOS 5 but not in iOS 4.x

Comment: Are there any new compiler warnings or runtime warnings?

Comment: Negative sir. I have even set break points in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to make sure it is getting called. (it is being called).

Comment: If you've solved your problem yourself it's customary on stack overflow to put your solution as an answer and accept it yourself; that way everyone can see that the question has been solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `UITableViewController` with your table view, [“When the table view is about to appear the first time it’s loaded, the table-view controller reloads the table view’s data.”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[“If you choose not to use `UITableViewController` for table-view management, you must replicate what this class gives you ‘for free.’”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW4)

The sample code in the second link sends `reloadData` to the table after setting its delegate and data source.  Perhaps in iOS 4, a table view automatically reloaded itself when loaded, and in iOS 5 it was changed to match the documentation.